# RVM not being detected when moved to /usr/local/rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

I have two users (deploy, developers) in ubuntu that should access the RVM.

I added these two users to `rvm` group, I'm expecting that when I'm at the deploy user. I can run `bundle install` 
but I'm getting 
`bundle: command not found`

I believe I also move the rvm to `/usr/local/rvm/` instead of user specific like `/developers/local/rvm/` or `/deploy/local/rvm/`

How can I use the rvm installed in `usr/local/rvm` for these two users.

Comment: bundle: command not found
run `$gem install bundler` this would install the bundler gem.

Comment: @Bijendra this one will only work if you install the RVM in the user specific in ubuntu (ex. /deploy/local/rvm/)
I moved the RVM to /usr/local/rvm so that it can be shared with another ubuntu user.

What I would like is to have multi-user rvm

Comment: But still you issue is not the missing rvm but that bundler gem is not installed.